# AngularJS with Kendo Grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an AngularJS app and am currently trying to insert a Kendo Grid.  I have a couple of questions about how to make this work.

1. I have a dropdown on the page that based on the selected value in that list, the grid should be updated for the information retrieved from the server for the selection.  I have tried to make my dataSource: data (i.e. data: $scope.model.waivers) be an object in my model but do not get any results for that.  I have been able to use the following code to get my initial results but nothing when the selection changes.

   ```
   transport: {
               read: function(e) {
                   waiverService.getCustomers($scope.model.customer.CustomerID)
                       .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                       e.success(data);
                   });
               }
           }
   ```
2. My second issue is I have several dropdown boxes on each row of the grid.  I have tried to use the information found in this [example](http://jsbin.com/obufum/5/edit?html,js,output) but I am getting a ReferenceError: getCategoryName is not defined.

   Can anyone provide help with either of these issues?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the first part by adding a watch to the model item for the object in my dropdown and the calling

```
$scope.grid.dataSource.read();
```

Now to resolve the issue of the dropdowns.